# leaflet markercluster add custom icon to all child cluster when a parent cluster is clicked

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have marker clusters at multiple levels (a child cluster can have clusters and so on).

Now, when I click on a parent cluster, I want to apply a custom icon to all the child clusters of the parent cluster to the bottom of the child clusters.

I tried collecting all child clusters and applying icons to them but it does not work.

```js
cluster.on('clusterclick', (e) => {
  const childClusters = e.layer._childClusters; 
  for(const c of childClusters){
    c.options.icon = this.getSelectedClusterIcon();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not use the documented `getAllChildMarkers()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to change the appearance of the "child" **clusters** of the one that is clicked, i.e. those that appear when you zoom in (but not the individual **markers** that appear ultimately when zoomed in even further enough)?

In that case, you could rely on the Leaflet.markercluster [`iconCreateFunction` option](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) and [`refreshClusters` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#refreshing-the-clusters-icon):

1. Create your MCG with `iconCreateFunction` that depends on some flags to generate different icons.
2. In the click event listener, mark all individual child **Markers** with some sort of flag. You can use the [`getAllChildMarkers` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-clusters-methods) to retrieve these Markers, as pointed out by Ivan.
3. Use the [`refreshClusters` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#refreshing-the-clusters-icon) to request MCG to re-evaluate your `iconCreateFunction` on the parent Clusters of those Markers.
4. In case you want to change the icon of Clusters that belong only to a certain zoom level (e.g. the one that is clicked, and/or 1 level higher for the immediate child Clusters), you could store those zoom levels in some state, and compare them to the Clusters' `_zoom` property within the `iconCreateFunction`.
5. In case you want to reset the Clusters, simply clear the flags and call again the `refreshClusters` method.

Something in the lines of:

```js
const mcg = L.markerClusterGroup({
  iconCreateFunction(cluster) {
    const isHighlighted = cluster.getAllChildMarkers().some((marker) => marker.flaggedZooms && marker.flaggedZooms[cluster._zoom]);
    return isHighlighted ? myIconHighlighted : myNormalIcon;
  },
}).on("clusterclick", function (e) {
  // In case we want to reset all other Clusters
  mcg.eachLayer((marker) => delete marker.flaggedZooms);

  const cluster = e.layer;

  // Mark the zoom level on the child Markers,
  // in case we want to change cluster icons only on some zoom
  for (const marker of cluster.getAllChildMarkers()) {
    marker.flaggedZooms = marker.flaggedZooms || {}; // Initialize if not already done
    marker.flaggedZooms[cluster._zoom + 1] = true; // Flag other zoom levels if desired
  }

  // Ensure Clusters icons are redrawn
  mcg.refreshClusters();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @ghybs, let me try this.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you very much.